# Sort a python dictionary into slots of equal intervals

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

How can we sort a dictionary based on dictionary keys and put them under consistent intervals?

For example, we have the following dictionary in python

```
{0: 1, 10: 3, 12: 2, 19: 4, 35: 5}
```

So in the above example, we have keys raning from `0 - 35`, and we want to put them in intervals of 10, which would imply the following:

```
interval 0-10 has values 1
interval 10-20 has values [3, 2, 4]
interval 20-30 has no values
interval 30-40 has values [5]
```

The final output should be similar to this:

```
{0: [1], 10: [3, 2, 4], 20: [0/null], 30: [5]
```

Any pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: @PedroMaia I was not sure how to get the intervals as keys, but your solution is spot on. If it's a `two-digit` number we can divide it by `10` which gives us the first integer and then multiply with `10`. Like your idea, thank you

Comment: @PedroMaia if we want to include missing intervals in the final output. Lets say here: `20: [0 or null]`. One way I could think is once we get the output, loop over the dictionary keys again and find the missing values? Can we do it in a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = {0: 1, 10: 3, 12: 2, 19: 4, 35: 5}
output = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in data.items():
    output[k // 10 * 10].append(v)
```

---

```
>>> dict(out)
{0: [1], 10: [3, 2, 4], 30: [5]}
```

**Edit**

If you must have all keys in the resulting dict then replace the default dict with a dict that builds itself the keys:

```
out = {k: [] for k in (range(0, (max(data)//10*10)+1, 10))}
for k, v in data.items():
    out[k // 10 * 10].append(v)
```

Comment: thanks, @Jab, is there a way to include empty intervals in the same iteration without a second loop?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: That's a better way to go.

Comment: I assume its `max(data)//10 * 10`

Comment: No.. It's supposed to be that so it goes to the right amount but it has end cases so to be correct it would be: `(max(data) // 10 * 10) + 1`

Comment: @Jab the solution is clear and concise, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To add missing values maybe store a variable with last and check if the gap between them is bigger than 10:

```py
a = {0: 1, 10: 3, 12: 2, 19: 4, 35: 5}
out = {}
last = 0
for i in a:
    b = int(i/10) * 10
    if (b - last) > 10:
        out[b-10] = [] # whatever you want it to be
    if b in out:
        out[b].append(a[i])
    else:
        out[b] = [a[i]]
    last = b
```

Output:

```
{0: [1], 10: [3, 2, 4], 20: [], 30: [5]}
```

Comment: cool, one more check though. If we have following input: `{0: 1, 10: 3, 12: 2, 19: 4, 45: 5}`, then output would be `{0: [1], 10: [3, 2, 4], 30: [], 40: [5]}` but not `{0: [1], 10: [3, 2, 4], 20: [], 30:[], 40: [5]}`